# When updating from a SVN respository, is it possible to update another repository, too?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

**The problem:** I often have to update two or more repositories: One for the project I'm working on and one or more libraries. Is there a way to "chain" the updates, so that every time I update *project X*, *library Y* gets updated, too?

I know, this is an unusual question, because I guess things like that would be part of a build process, but as the things are now at my workplace, this is not possible (yet).

I'm using SVN 1.5 together with TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like something you should be able to accomplish using [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html). Essentially what it does is to "link" in an external (separate) svn-repository into a directory in your working copy.

Tortoise has excellent support for externals allowing you to select whether or not to export externals as a part of an WC-export or not. You can find a quick introduction to TortoiseSVN and externals at [http://justaddwater.dk/](http://justaddwater.dk/2007/10/23/setting-up-subversion-externals-with-tortoisesvn/). It might be a little out of date but it should get you started. The [tortoise svn guide](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html#tsvn-howto-common-externals) also offers some guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [SVN Externals Definition](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) which should do what you want.

Comment: Beat me to it by 7 seconds ;)